# Perl: Use of uninitialized value

Tags: perl

Below is a small excerpt from my code in Perl. I am getting the error

> Error: Use of uninitialized value $key

but have no clue why. `$key` changes within the inner for loop, but I can't access the value outside. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Cwd;

my $MAX_PROCESSES=16;

print(cwd);
print "\n";
my $num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args < 2) {
    print "\nUsage: rot_align_spider.pl <folder containing particles> <reference>\n";
exit;
}

my $folder_name=$ARGV[0];
my $ref=$ARGV[1];

print "Input, $folder_name $ref\n";
system('rm -r rot_align_spider');
system('mkdir rot_align_spider');
my $mv_cmd="cp $folder_name/*.app rot_align_spider";
system($mv_cmd);
system("cp $ref rot_align_spider");

chdir "rot_align_spider";

my @files=`ls *.app`;
#print "@files";

print (cwd);
print "\n";
foreach (@files) {
   chomp($_);
   #print "$_\n";
   my $new_name=$_;
   #print "$new_name\n";
   $new_name=~s/\.app$//g;
   my $rename_files_cmd="mv $_ $new_name";
   print "Renaming file $_ to $new_name\n";
   system($rename_files_cmd);
}

my $ref_vol=substr($ref,0,-4);
my $new_ref_vol=$ref_vol."_iter_0";
my $ref_cp_cmd="cp $ref $new_ref_vol.spi";
system($ref_cp_cmd);
@files=`ls "$folder_name"*.spi`;

for(my $i=0;$i<1;$i++) {
    my $pm=new Parallel::ForkManager($MAX_PROCESSES);
    my $ref_id=$i+1;
    my $key; #$key defined here
    my $j;
    for($j=0;$j<scalar(@files);$j++) {
        my $pid=$pm->start and next;    
        chomp($files[$j]);
        my $base_name=substr($files[$j],0,-4);
        #print "$base_name\n";
        my $soc_file_name=$base_name.".soc";
        #print "$soc_file_name\n";
        my $exp_vol=substr($files[$j],0,-4);
        my $aligned_exp_vol=$exp_vol."_iter";
        my $ref_vol=substr($ref,0,-4);
        $key=$j+1;
        open SOC,">$soc_file_name" || die "Can't open file: $!";
        print SOC <<EOF;

MD
RESULTS OFF

MD
FBS ON

OR 3Q [phi],[the],[psi],[cc]
$exp_vol
$new_ref_vol
29
0,0,0

SD $key,[phi],[the],[psi],[cc]
cc2n_spider
SD E 

ROT
$exp_vol
$aligned_exp_vol
[phi],[the],[psi]
F
U

END
EOF
    close SOC;
    my $spider_cmd="spider_linux_mp_intel64 soc\/spi \@$base_name";
    print "$spider_cmd\n";
    system($spider_cmd);
    print "$key\n"; #$key printed here in the inner-loop
    $pm->finish;    
}
#$key=$j;
$pm->wait_all_children; 
print "$ref_id $key\n"; #$key printed here in the outer-loop
my $avg_soc_file_name=$folder_name.".soc";
$new_ref_vol=$ref_vol."_iter_".$ref_id;
open SOC,">$avg_soc_file_name" || die "Can't open file: $!";
print SOC <<EOF;

MD
RESULTS OFF

MD
FBS ON

AS S
${folder_name}_bin4x_***_iter
1-$key
A
$new_ref_vol

END
EOF
    close SOC;
            my $spider_cmd="spider_linux_mp_intel64 soc\/spi \@$folder_name";
            print "$spider_cmd\n";
            system($spider_cmd);
 }
```

Log file after run -

```
  **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 28
  **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 24
  **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 25
  **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 29
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 32
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 31
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 33
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 34
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 35
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 36
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 38
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 39
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 41
   **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 42
    **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 40
    **** SPIDER NORMAL STOP ****
 37
  Use of uninitialized value $key in concatenation (.) or string at  ../../rot_align_spider.pl line 104.
  Use of uninitialized value $key in concatenation (.) or string at ../../rot_align_spider.pl line 108.
  1
```

Comment: Is the ) meant to be there, just after the 20 ?

Comment: Without the superfluous `)` it works for me.

Comment: Ditto. Is this a simplified example, intended to show a warning happening in real code? If so, either provide the actual code, or a less-reduced example that actually *shows* the problem.

Comment: Code with bracket doesn't compile. Code without works fine. This is either a typo or an incomplete example.

Comment: You are getting multiple downvotes because, apart from the usual advice to avoid C-style `for` loops, the code you show works fine. There is no way to guess what may be wrong with your real code unless you publish it, but then we would be glad to help

Comment: Sorry guyz! The braces was a typo. The simpler code works perfectly without the braces. I have now pasted the actual code and the output. Did I make a big blunder somewhere?

Comment: @JaganMohan Are you sure `@files` contains anything? Could you try `say scalar(@files);` just before the loop?

Comment: @Biffen `@files` does contain the right values. And you can also see from the log that the loop actually ran 42 times (that's why it printed the value of key correctly). There are 42 elements in @files.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in the inner loop has a `next` in it that the main process takes after each `start` call (because in the main process `start` returns the non-zero PID of the child; I'm guessing that it returns `-1` if it can't `start` like a system-level `fork` does) and thus `$key` remains undefined in the main thread through out the loop.

Additionally, you can not set `$key` in a forked process and have it change in the parent: they are separate processes with no shared data.  You can use the second argument to [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager)'s `finish` method to send data back from child and `run_on_finish` to gather it.  Read the [RETRIEVING DATASTRUCTURES from child processes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager#RETRIEVING-DATASTRUCTURES-from-child-processes) section of the module's document for more information.

Lastly, you may only get 16 children because `$MAX_PROCESSES` is 16 and `wait_all_children` doesn't happen until the loop is finished; adding `wait_for_available_procs();` in the loop just before the call to `start` should help.